# Change value of other options in selects, after first option is chosen

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/tjede1nm/

I have two selects which show values of chosen options in input box.

What I want is after choosing the first option in one of dropdowns, the other options should change on keyup value to '0'.

For example, if I choose 'Camera', then values of 'Diamond' and 'Spaceship' should be '0' in both dropdowns.

```js
// Prevent choosing same option in both selects
$('select[name*="select-option"]').change(function(){
    var prize = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

    $('select[name*="select-option"]').not(this).each(function(){
        $('option', this).each(function(){
            if( $(this).text() == prize ){
                $(this).prop('disabled',true);
            }
        });
    });
});

// Show values in input
$("#cd-dropdown0").change(function()
{
  $("#id_search0").val($(this).val());
  $("#id_search0").keyup();
});

$("#cd-dropdown1").change(function()
{
  $("#id_search1").val($(this).val());
  $("#id_search1").keyup();
});

// --------------------HELP-----------------------------

$('select[name*="select-option"]').bind("change keyup",function(){

var item = ("option:selected");

$('option').not(item).bind("each keyup",function()
{
    $(this).val('0');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search" value="" id="id_search0" disabled/>        

<select id="cd-dropdown0" class="cd-select" name="select-option">
 <option value="0" selected>Choose your prize</option>
 <option value="1" class="search-btn" data-search="camera">Camera</option>
 <option value="2" class="search-btn" data-search="diamonds">Diamonds</option>
 <option value="3" class="search-btn" data-search="spaceship">Spaceship</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="search" value="" id="id_search1" disabled/>    
<select id="cd-dropdown1" class="cd-select" name="select-option">
 <option value="0" selected>Choose your prize</option>
 <option value="1" class="search-btn" data-search="camera">Camera</option>
 <option value="2" class="search-btn" data-search="diamonds">Diamonds</option>
 <option value="3" class="search-btn" data-search="spaceship">Spaceship</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For example, If I choose 'Camera', then values of 'Diamond' and 'Spaceship' should be '0' in both dropdowns. This is all you want to achieve?

Comment: Confusing question? I need more information.

Comment: And if user select 'Diamond' then what should be the output ?? - You should post more details.

Comment: Can you explain `keyup` function here. Apparently its not keyup() in jquery(http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)...

Comment: @void: if I choose 'Diamond', then values of 'Camera' and 'Spaceship' would be '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('option', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == prize) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
               //Set value of options to 0 in both dropdowns where value not equal to selected value
                $('select[name*="select-option"] option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').val('0');
            }
        });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjede1nm/1/)